# output xml with a certain attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Sorry for being a total noob here, but maybe s/o can point me in the right direction!?
I got code off the net and am trying to make it work, but it will not :(
the xml is this:

```
<bla>
    <blub>
        <this that="one">test one</this>
        <this that="two">test two</this>
        <this that="three">test three</this>
    </blub>
</bla>
```

And I want to have "this" displayed, where "that" == "two", as you can probably tell ;)
but it will only work for the first (one"), not for "two" or "three".

Why does it not continue to the 2nd and 3rd element? Thanks for any advice!

```
  XElement tata = XElement.Load(@"\\somewhere\test.xml");

  var tutu = from titi in tata.Elements("blub")
             where (string)titi.Element("this").Attribute("that") == "two"
             select titi.Element("this");
  foreach (XElement soso in tutu)
  {
           Console.WriteLine(soso.Value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
where (string)titi.Element("this").Attribute("that") == "two"
```

In particular the `Element()`, which *gets the first (in document order) child element with the specified XName* which happens to be `test one` in your case.

Instead, use `XDocument` rather than `XElement` and look at all elements in the document:

```
XDocument tata = XDocument.Load(@"\\somewhere\test.xml");

var tutu = from titi in tata.Descendants("this")
           where titi.Attribute("that").Value == "two"
           select titi;
```